# NodeJS Amazon AWS S3 getObject how to send file in API response to download

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building a NodeJS Express API that accepts a filepath as a parameter, gets an object from S3 and then sends the file back in the API response.

I am using the NodeJS Amazon AWS S3 SDK  `@aws-sdk/client-s3`.

I have everything working up to returning the file in the API response.

Here is the controller. This is working to get the object as a readable stream from S3.

```
const consoleLogger = require('../logger/logger.js').console;
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const s3client = new S3Client({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION || 'us-east-1' });

const awsCtrl = {};

awsCtrl.getObject = async (key) => {

  // Get object from Amazon S3 bucket
  let data;
  try {
    // Data is returned as a ReadableStream
    data = await s3client.send(new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET, Key: key }));
    console.log("Success", data);
  } catch (e) {
    consoleLogger.error("AWS S3 error: ", e);
    const awsS3Error = {
      name: e.name || null,
      status: e.$metadata.httpStatusCode || 500
    };
    throw awsS3Error;
  }

  return data;

}

module.exports = awsCtrl;
```

Here is where the controller is called.

```
router.get('/:fileId', (req, res, next) => {

  return filesCtrl.deliverFile(req, res);

});

filesCtrl.deliverFile = async (req, res) => {
  /* Get object from AWS S3 */
  let fileStream;
  try {
    fileStream = await awsCtrl.getObject(filePath);
  } catch (e) {
    consoleLogger.error(`Unable to get object from AWS S3`, e);
    if (e.status && e.status === 404) {
      result.error = `Not found`;
      result.status = 404;
      return res.status(result.status).json(result);
    }
    return res.status(e.status || 500).json(result);
  }

  // Set file header
  res.attachment(filename);

  // HOW TO RETURN THE FILE IN API RESPONSE TO DOWNLOAD?
  // not working
  //return fileStream.pipe(res); 
}
```

**Question:**

How do I return the file in the Node JS Express API response to download?

Note: I've already tried other suggestions in a few other questions but none of the solutions have worked to return the file in the API response.

I tried the answer in this question here but the file is downloaded on the server side, the file needs to be returned in the API response. [How to save file from S3 using aws-sdk v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689614/how-to-save-file-from-s3-using-aws-sdk-v3)

Also the answer in this question here is using the v2 version of the SDK and this is v3. There is no .createReadStream() method anymore. [NodeJS download file from AWS S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55705550/nodejs-download-file-from-aws-s3-bucket?rq=1)

Comment: I might be missing something... what does "API response" mean in your context? Is this express? I'm not familiar with v3 of the sdk, but v2 would return a buffer... are you asking how to return binary data?

Comment: @404 Yes this is a NodeJS Express API. I want to return the file in the Express API response 'res' to download the file on the client side.

Comment: You really want to sent it as a file for sure ? **Or** is it ok if you send a download a link to client, which can be used by client to download the file in FE ?

Comment: If you are using lambda don't do this, use S3 presigned urls! You will pay for download time from S3 to lambda, and download time from lambda to end user.

Comment: @Abiram yes it needs to be sent as a file to download on the client side.

Comment: @Lucasz Thank you we are not using lambda this is a standalone NodeJS application on our own servers.

Comment: `ReadableStream` is part of Web Streams API (as implemented in `node:stream/web`). I can't confirm that it is what s3 sdk really uses, but if that is the case, `pipe()` is not supposed to be defined. Instead, it should be `pipeTo()`. But I'm afraid you're going to have to convert web standard stream to node `Readable` stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Server Side**

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

router.get('/getfilefroms3', async (req, res, next) => {

  aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: config.secret_access_key,
    accessKeyId: config.access_key_id,
    signatureVersion: config.signature_version,
    region: config.region
  })

  const s3 = new aws.S3({ });

  var params = { Bucket: config.sample_bucket_name, Key: req.query.filename };

  s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(200);
      res.end('Error Fetching File');
    }
    else {
      res.attachment(params.Key); // Set Filename
      res.type(data.ContentType); // Set FileType
      res.send(data.Body);        // Send File Buffer
    }
  });

})
```

**Client Side**

**If you are using Web Application you can use any HTTP REST API Client like Axios or Fetch, The Download Manager will capture the file.**

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5001/getfilefroms3?filename=sample.pdf'
```

**If you are using NodeJS Application**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function (url, destination, callback) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
    http.get(url, function (response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function () {
            file.close(callback);
        });
    });
}

var fileToDownload = "sample.pdf"

download("http://localhost:5001/getfilefroms3?filename=" + fileToDownload, "./" + fileToDownload, () => { console.log("File Downloaded") })
```